# Does Word for Mac 2016 ensure stability of documents made by Windows PCs?

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-word, fonts

If I created a file in Word on a Windows PC with some fancy fonts, shadows etc. and then I were to edit some of the text in Word on a MAC, would the same original fancy fonts and shadows still remain in Word on a Windows PC? Are there any dangers that I may lose this design that is not visible on the MAC operating system?

Thank you in advance

*Note: It was suggested in the Super User chatroom that the option to embed fonts in Word 2016 on Mac may eliminate this issue, but I do not believe that the issue is entirely based on fonts.*

Comment: I'd always use .pdf for anything that really needs to preserve its appearance. Word is just not an app for doing that, or in fact anything with strict layout requirements, even between different versions on the same platform. Its ubiquity is not a result of its capability.

Comment: Note to down voters: Word's inability to render correctly cross-platform is not in itself a good reason to downvote any question doubting that ability.

Comment: The best way to find out is to actually try it out (assuming you have access to a Mac and a Windows PC). Keep a backup copy of the original `DOCX` file, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is, "Does Word embed the fonts that it uses." The answer is, it depends. It depends on the settings you use [as explained here](https://blogs.office.com/2015/07/06/document-font-embedding-demystified/).

> "All TrueType and OpenType fonts have “embedding permissions” encoded
>   within them, these are typically set by the font’s supplier, and are
>   defined as part of the OpenType font file specification. There are a
>   number of settings, but the main ones of interest are as follows:
>
> - **No embedding—** The font supplier does not allow embedding. These fonts are quite rare.
> - **Print and preview—** The font supplier allows for embedding but the document is locked and cannot be edited. Most third-party fonts
>     have this setting.
> - **Editable—** The font supplier allows the font to be embedded within a document and allows the document to be edited using that
>     embedded font.
> - **Installable—** This is the most permissive setting. The font supplier allows the font to be embedded within a document, and permits
>     the document viewing application to permanently install the font on
>     the user’s computer. Most applications treat these fonts like those
>     set to Editable embedding."

OS X is compatible with TrueType and OpenType fonts.